# Warn against missing std:: prefixes due to ADL

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, argument-dependent-lookup, clang-tidy

It is possible to omit the `std::` namespace for `<algorithm>`s when the argument types are in that namespace, which is usually the case. Is there any warning or clang-tidy rule that finds such omissions?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> v;
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto){});
return 0;
```

The above example, compiled with the latest clang and -Wall, -Wextra and -Wpedantic does not emit any diagnostic:

https://godbolt.org/z/dTsKbbEKe

Comment: ADL is one of Titus Winters's *Scary Stories*.  Are you trying to disable ADL?  Warn about ADL use?  Lean into ADL to get diagnostics when `std::` is superfluous due to ADL?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a warning to be emitted if a function from `namespace std` is called without the `std::` qualification?

Comment: @Eljay ADL is totally fine for `operator<<` and the likes. I just want to enforce usage of `std::` prefixes for explicit library function calls. It's mostly a coding guidelines thing.

Comment: I see.  Hmm.  I'd like the same thing.  (Titus had a good presentation on how to thwart ADL, but that was for your own code, not `std`.)  If you took the C++ source (like GCC or Clang) and disable ADL (except still enable for `operator@`), you might be able to come close.

Comment: Notice that given code doesn't necessary compile as `std::vector<int>::iterator` might simply be `int*` (or type not in namespace `std`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an open change in tidy that could be used to flag this:

- [D72282 - [clang-tidy] Add `bugprone-unintended-adl`](https://reviews.llvm.org/D72282)

> ### [patch] Summary
>
> This patch adds `bugprone-unintended-adl` which flags uses of ADL that are not on the provided whitelist.
>
> ### bugprone-unintended-adl
>
> Finds usages of ADL (argument-dependent lookup), or potential ADL in the case of templates, that are not on the provided lists of allowed identifiers and namespaces. [...]
>
> **.. option:: `IgnoreOverloadedOperators`**
>
> If non-zero, ignores calls to overloaded operators using operator
> syntax     (e.g. `a + b`), but not function call syntax (e.g.
> `operator+(a, b)`).     Default is `1`.
>
> **.. option:: `AllowedIdentifiers`**
>
> Semicolon-separated list of names that the check ignores. Default
> is
> `swap;make_error_code;make_error_condition;data;begin;end;rbegin;rend;crbegin;crend;size;ssize;empty`.
>
> **.. option:: `AllowedNamespaces`**
>
> Semicolon-separated list of namespace names (e.g. `foo;bar::baz`).
> If the     check finds an unqualified call that resolves to a function
> in a namespace     in this list, the call is ignored. Default is an
> empty list.

There seems to have been no activity on the patch since July 2020, though, but if this is of interest of the OP, the OP could try to resuscitate the patch.